# Contents Posted on Facebook Page not visible?

Tags: c#, asp.net, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am trying to post on my Facebook page using c# and Facebook sdk. I am able to post the contents on my Facebook page but it is not properly visible to others. Even the admin of the page can view only the heading of the post but can not see the picture or the content of that post. But the admin of the page can see the contents of the post by clicking on ">" this sign beside post to page. Please guide me why this is happening and how can I resolve this.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    CheckAuthorization();
}

private void CheckAuthorization()
{
    string app_id = "My App ID";
    string app_secret = "My App Secret";
    string scope = "publish_stream, publish_actions";
    if (Request["code"] == null)
    {
        Response.Redirect(string.Format("https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/authorize?client_id={0}&redirect_uri={1}&scope={2}", app_id, Request.Url.AbsoluteUri, scope));
    }
    else
    {
        Dictionary<string, string> tokens = new Dictionary<string, string>();
        string url = string.Format("https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?client_id={0}&redirect_uri={1}&scope={2}&code={3}&client_secret={4}",app_id,Request.Url.AbsoluteUri,scope,Request["code"].ToString(),app_secret);
        HttpWebRequest request = System.Net.WebRequest.Create(url) as HttpWebRequest;

        using (HttpWebResponse response = request.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse)
        {
            StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream());

            string vals = reader.ReadToEnd();

            foreach (string token in vals.Split('&'))
            {
                tokens.Add(token.Substring(0, token.IndexOf("=")), token.Substring(token.IndexOf("=") + 1, token.Length - token.IndexOf("=") - 1));
            }
        }
        string access_token = tokens["access_token"];



        var client = new FacebookClient(access_token);

        dynamic parameters = new ExpandoObject();
        parameters.message = "Hello This Is My First Post To Facebook";
        parameters.link = "http://www.google.com";
        parameters.picture = "http://www.mywebsite.com/picture/welcome.jpg";
        parameters.name = "Hello Users We welcome you all";
        parameters.caption = "Posted By Ashish";



        client.Post("/My Facebook Page ID/feed", parameters);
    }
}
```

Please guide me where I am doing wrong since I am trying this for the first time after following certain posts on several websites.

Comment: Look at the string returned by `client.Post` and see what it tells you

Comment: @GrawCube I am passing my Facebook Page ID within Client.Post()

Comment: I can very clearly see that. You need to debug `client.Post("/My Facebook Page ID/feed", parameters);` and see what the method returns! It returns an object (quite probably string in this case) so you should very well be able to see its contents.

Comment: @GrawCube After debugging I could see that Client.Post() accepts access token but AppId and AppSecret both are NULL...!!
Actually I am passing my Fan Page ID within Client.Post()
Do I need to pass Admin's Page ID???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using the **user access token** to post a feed to the page. So, the feeds are posted on behalf the user (not the page), which are visible as summary on the timeline.

If you post the feed on behalf of page admin itself (so that the post is visible normally on the timeline), you need to use the **page access token** with `publish_actions` permissions.

And to get the page access token you need to query: `/<page-id>?fields=access_token` using the normal user token with `manage_pages` permission.

Comment: Yes you are right after debugging I have seen that `string access_token` is capturing User Access token. How can I pass Page access token??? Please guide me. You have also mentioned how to get page access token i.e. you are asking me to pass the query. But here I have a doubt, Do I need to assign my User access token in fields???

Comment: I'm not getting what you are trying to say. Read carefully what I've answered, it's pretty straight forward!

Comment: I understood what you tried to explain. But my question is where I have to input the query you provided me??

Comment: Wherevr you want. What do you mean by where?

Comment: You said that I am using user access token. After debugging I have seen that access_token is holding user access token. As you explained that the feeds are posted on behalf of the user (not the page), which are visible as summary on the timeline that's exactly true.
Then you mentioned that I have to use Page access token.
Now my question is How I can use page action token within my code??
And how can I get my page access token from?
Please guide me. I am totally confused. I am not able to find my page access token on facebook.developers site

Comment: To get the page access token , I've already mentioned: `And to get the page access token you need to query: /<page-id>?fields=access_token using the normal user token with manage_pages permission.`. To use this token, simply add the token with the parameters list, the parameter be `access_token`

Comment: I followed your instruction and it worked. But there is a problem, in place of page ID whenever I am providing the administrators page ID the post is successfully posted on my Admin's Facebook Wall but not on my Facebook Fan Page. I want that the post should be posted on my Facebook Fan Page. For that what I need to do???
Please guide me.

Comment: If you use `/page-id/feed`, the post will be published on page itslef not on the user's wall. Pl check carefully. Also if the answer has solved your problem you can accept/vote the answer

Comment: Within `Client.Post("/Fan Page ID/feed", parameters)` I am passing my Fan Page ID and within `string access_token = tokens["/<Admin Page ID>?fields=User Access Token"];`
And Yes I will definitely accept your answer. Since I am trying to post on my Fan Page which is not happening, for that I need your guidance friend.

Comment: Thanks a lot for helping me out to solve this issue.

Answer (score 0):

I just want to add that sometimes your app is in MODE : **developer** so everything you do is visible only to the developers, it is actually the problem i had, So you need to go to your application Dashboard and look for something like "**Review**" *[i hate giving exact paths because Facebook changes everything every once in a while]*, and look for something like : **Your app is in development and unavailable to the public**, put it to public